# FOSUserBundle no validation made

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I've created a User class in my Bundle based on FOS\UserBundle\Model\User\BaseUser to register my users.

Here is my User.php :

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

// Constructor
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


}
```

Here is my UserType.php :

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('valider', 'submit')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'CSW78\Bundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'fos_user_registration';
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
}
}
```

I overrode register.html.twig, putting it in /app/resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration and it is called.
Here is my register.html.twig :

```
{% block body %}
<div id="cadre" class="arrondi">
    <h1>Inscription</h1>
    <br>
    {% block fos_user_content %}
        <form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register form-horizontal">
            <div id="fos_user_registration_form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.username, 'Identifiant :',     {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label'}}) }}
                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                        {{ form_widget(form.username, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.email, 'Email :',  {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label'}}) }}
                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                        {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first, 'Mot de passe :', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label'}}) }}
                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second, 'Mot de passe (confirmation) :', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-xs-5 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label'}}) }}
                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
                        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{ form_widget(form._token, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.valider, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-info btn-responsive btn-color'}}) }}
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>
        </form>
    {% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is there is no validation made when I click on the submit button.

I thought that the validation constraints would inherit from the BaseUser validation constraints.

> Is there something else to specify to call the BaseUser validation constraints on my User object ?
>
> Another question: what if I want to customize the error messages, should I override the validation.xml file to do that ?

Thank you.

David

Comment: What validation do you mean? the Validatotion Component or the "this field shouldn't be empty"?

Comment: The field shouldn't be empty, password mismatch etc. and the ability to customize it, with Asserts